# Upon scrolling my navbar expands to the right. How comes?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm fairly new to css and website design in general. I have created a site with a navbar, that scrolls down with the page, so it always stays on top:

```
 <div class="topnav" id="navbar">
     <a href="/start">Startseite</a>
     <a href="/overview">Übersicht</a>
     ...
```

This does work, I have a Sticky-Class in my css, as well as some design options:

```
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}


.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and this js which assigns it to my navbar, when it's scrolling so far up, that it would disappear.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
 }
```

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

As you can see on the picture, from the moment on that the navbar is in a "scrolled" state, it expands a little bit to the right, so that it hits the side of the page.

This is a behaviour which I find very confusing, can anyone explain to me why this happenes, and how I can get it to just keep its size with the space to the side of the page? I figured it could have to do something with the expand 100%, but why is it then not bumping into the left side of the page as well?

Comment: Your stick class... Add `left:0; right:0;` Let me know if there's a difference.

Comment: Yaay, now it expands to both sides xD

Comment: Update your HTML, I'll create a fiddle for you.

Comment: What if you use 100vw instead of 100% and left: 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you scroll because the div is not properly bound to the viewport.

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  max-width: 92vw;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 92vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="navbar">
  <a href="/start">Startseite</a>
  <a href="/overview">Übersicht</a>
  <a href="/about">Über uns</a>
  <a style="float:right">
    <form action="/search">
      <label for="player_seach">Suche:
                        <input id="player_seach" name="player_search">
                    </label>
    </form>
  </a>
  <a href="/profile" style="float:right">
            </a>
</div>

<div style="min-height: 500px; width: 100%">
</div>
```

You can add media queries to help declutter the navbar upon resizing.
Happy learning!

Comment: no, it still happenes. I will add some bigger pictures to the question, so you can see what I mean :)

Comment: I added two pictures that illustrate, what your suggested sticky class does

Comment: That bit of space that surrounding your navbar before scrolling begins can be removed by adding `*{margin: 0}`. I've updated my answer as per your response.

Comment: But I do explicily want that space to surround my navbar ^^

Comment: Then you'll have to use `margin` to style your nav. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That will move it in from both sides, and it still has a difference in size when scrolling... It should simply stay the same when scrolling, but it seems to not do it...

Comment: Updated once again. I am confident this time, your issue is resolved.

Comment: That somehow broke the bar in another way... here's an image: https://imgur.com/a/omRIu1o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217189/discussion-between-beulah-akindele-and-monamona).